# What does "share" mean in "...qualities that you share with your friends and family"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am doing a course and there is a question:

> Please select the 2 or 3 most important values or qualities that you share with your friends and family.

I am not sure what "share" means here.

Does that mean that me and my friends/family have values or qualities in common?

Or does that mean that I have some values or qualities that I share or want to share with friends and family but they don't have them?

Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Values that you have in common. "Share" in the sense of "tell about" seems unlikely to be common with "values" (unless you're evangelizing), but "shared values" is a very common expression that this question is alluding to.